# Can a nuxtjs application store be something dynamic?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

When we work with an API, logically, we should split our "store" folder into several files, cutting our logic across our different entities.

For example, an API that deals with users as well as books.

- Store/

  - books.js
  - users.js

It is VERY likely that at some point in our application, we will have to search the data in bulk. (Either all users or all books). Or more specifically (only 1 book, only 1 user; identified by an ID).

My question is the following:

**Can I afford to make fewer files in the store, if the methods I use to retrieve the books are also used to retrieve the users?**

For example, I could have a generic method, which would fetch "entity" passed as a parameter.

```
async genericFetch({commit}, entity) {
  const req = await this.$axios.get(`/${entity}`)
  commit('setData', {entity, values: req.data})
}
```

I will use this method when mounting a component, e.g.

We can imagine the same thing with getters or mutations (we can imagine that in my example, the commit `setData` will precisely modify the data according to the entity passed as a parameter as well).

I'd be happy to know how you organize your store.
According to some projects, it's not uncommon to have to repeat ourselves through the different files in the store, only because we're not going to work with the same data, although we're doing pretty much the same thing.

Nevertheless, the question I'm asking suggests a real problem of clarity in the code (and therefore, I imagine it would be more complicated to maintain the code).

Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Totally fine for me to have something generic, I'd even recommend it if it helps reducing code duplication. Of course, abstraction can be sometimes harder to understand but in this case, it should be totally fine. Also, don't forget to allow for some flexibility afterwards: let's say if your `genericFetch` doesn't work for a specific entity because it have changed too much compared to the basic one it was at the start.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I go in the way of a "generic store", am I obliged to manage the whole store in a single file? or to manage different states through the application?
I was also wondering if it was possible (and/or advisable) to manage the "generic" side (i.e. all redundant methods), and maybe the methods where logic without abstraction layer is much more understandable in another file.